# Javascript - Sum two specific array numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I have an array that I need to the following with:

1. arranged from lowest to highest.
2. Select the middle two numbers.
3. Sum the middle two scores.

Am I on the right track?

```
var numArray = [2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2];

numArray.sort((a, b) => a - b);

var sum = numArray[2] + numArray[3];
```

I think Array.reduce can be used somehow?

var sum = numArray[2] + numArray[3]; gives me two numebrs together and not their sum.

How do I do math function sum rather than combined two variables into one?

---

Edit: DrafsApp for Mac was adding two values "2" and "2" into "22"

I had to change the code to this and it works:

```
var sum = Number(numArray[2]) + Number(numArray[3]);
```

Comment: yeah, you are and it is giving me sum of two number exactly what you expected...

Comment: _"gives me two numbers together"_: sounds like you're using strings and not integers, so it suggests your array in your question is wrong.

Comment: @slyfox If your array is strings, not numbers, please edit the post to show that as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The code is returning the sum as expected.

```js
var numArray = [2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2];

numArray.sort((a, b) => a - b);
//Sorted array - [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]

var sum = numArray[2] + numArray[3];
//sum = 2 + 2

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: I was getting 22 because DraftsApp adds the two values together. This adjustment works: ```var sum = Number(numArray[2]) + Number(numArray[3]);```

Comment: @slyfox this only happens if you have array of strings, not numbers. the code u suggested in the question contains only numbers.